# Perl Array of Hashes - Reference each hash within array?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference, perl-data-structures

I am trying to create an array of hashes, and I am wondering how to reference each hash within the array?

For eg:

```
while(<INFILE>)    
{    
  my $row = $_;    
  chomp $row;    
  my @cols = split(/\t/,$row);    
  my $key = $cols[0]."\t".$cols[1];     

  my @total = (); ## This is my array of hashes - wrong syntax???    

  for($i=2;$i<@cols;$i++)    
  {    
    $total[$c++]{$key} += $cols[$i];      
  }    
}

close INFILE;

foreach (sort keys %total)  #sort keys for one of the hashes within the array - wrong syntax???    
{    
  print $_."\t".$total[0]{$_}."\n";    
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The logic in this is a bit more broken than just addressing the use of hashes and arrays. Maybe you could explain what it is you're trying to achieve and we can possibly point you in the right direction.

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference can be very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need

```
my @total = ();
```

This:

```
my @total;
```

is sufficient for what you are after. No special syntax needed to declare that your array will contain hashes.

There's probably different ways of doing the `foreach` part, but this should work:

```
foreach (sort keys %{$total[$the_index_you_want]}) {
  print $_."\t".$total[$the_index_you_want]{$_}."\n";
}
```

[BTW, declaring `my @total;` inside that loop is probably not what you want (it would be reset on each line). Move that outside the first loop.]

And `use strict; use warnings;`, obviously :-)

Comment: You should always initialize your variables. Although it doesn't do it any more, Apache would restart a mod_perl CGI without resetting the data space to zeros. This meant that whatever values were in there before were re-used. Program defensively: always initialize your variables.

Comment: @shawnhcorey: No, program defensively: Use lexical ("my") variables and declare them in the smallest possible scope. If you don't use globals (or lexicals whose scope is the entire program), it doesn't matter whether the data space is zeroed out or not because the variables' values will be lost when they go out of scope.

Comment: Sorry, lexical variables are scoped to the block they're in or, if outside of a block, to the file they're in.  They cannot be accessed from another file, unlike 'our' variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I get:

```
print join( "\t", @$_{ sort keys %$_ } ), "\n" foreach @total;
```

I'm simply iterating through `@total` and for each hashref taking a *slice* in sorted order and joining those values with tabs.

If you didn't need them in sorted order, you could just

```
print join( "\t", values %$_ ), "\n" foreach @total;
```

But I also would compress the line processing like so:

```
my ( $k1, $k2, @cols ) = split /\t/, $row;
my $key                = "$k1\t$k2";
$totals[ $_ ]{ $key } += $cols[ $_ ] foreach 0..$#cols;
```

But with [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils), you could also do this:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw<pairwise>;
my ( $k1, $k2, @cols ) = split /\t/, $row;
my $key                = "$k1\t$k2";
pairwise { $a->{ $key } += $b } @totals => @cols;
```